# Loading data from a large csv file to the sql server using map reduce

Tags: sql-server, csv, hadoop, mapper, reducers

I am pretty naive to hadoop and I want to load csv data into my local sql server using mapper and reducer. Is it possible to do? If so how could I do it? Can somone please explain the steps to be followed or direct me to an article that explains it in a step by step basis.

I believe if it could be done mapper alone is sufficient to do the job. Can someone correct me if I am wrong.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: i guess you can use "Sqoop"

Answer (score 0):

No need to use long Map reduce program for loading data to SQL from local, you can simply use export command in Apache Sqoop for this with below syntax:

sqoop -export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/db --username root --password  --table  --export-dir